# Substitute to OR in Mysql Syntax

Tags: mysql

I am creating query in mysql, that selects list of names in database where all the first names are JULIO and all Surnames are LOPEZ. I want to ask if there is an OR keyword in Mysql syntax? If there is none, is there any substitute to it?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM client_information WHERE fname = 'JULIO' OR lname = 'LOPEZ';
```

I know the above syntax is wrong because of OR, thanks for the response!

Comment: There is OR operator in mysql.

Comment: `first names are JULIO and all Surnames are LOPEZ` makes it sound like `AND` would fit better than `OR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** there is `OR` in mysql have you googled it or searched it or tryed it?

you can use `||`, `OR`  both are or

check functions and operators in mysql

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/func-op-summary-ref.html

Answer (score 1):

'OR' is in fact a keyword in MySQL. I am not sure what is wrong with your query, I ran it fine and it worked. There is no reason why that query should not work.